# Javascript input select option com data-select

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código javascript e cria adicionar o atributo data-select

Algo deste género mas criar o select em javascript http://jsfiddle.net/dbg0a4zy/

Tal como neste option em php mas em javascript

```
 echo'<option data-select="'.$distrito.'" value= "'.$registoq['id_escalao'].'">'.$registoq['id_escalao'].' </option>';  

 // Celula 2 -Escalão
    // Cria um <td>
    var diasem = row.insertCell(2);
     // Cria o select
    var esc = document.createElement('select');
    // Da o nome ao select
    esc.name = 'escalao[]';
    esc.className = "form-control";
    esc.options[0] = new Option("iniciados", "1");
         esc.options[1] = new Option("juniores", "2");
 esc.options[2] = new Option("seniores", "3);
    diasem.appendChild(esc);
```

Este é o código que uso para apenas aparecerem os escalões associados aquela modalidade, necessito do data-select ou existe outra forma ? é que não consigo criar o atributo data-select em javascript

```
var selects = $('select[name="escalao[]"] option');
$('select[name="modalidade[]"]').on('change', function () {
var select = this.value;
var novoSelect = selects.filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('select') == select;
});
$('select[name="escalao[]"]').html(novoSelect);
});
```

Comment: Tem muitos problemas nesse código... o código está assim num ficheiro ou juntaste PHP e JavaScript só aqui na pergunta?

Comment: Esta tudo junto e funciona apesar de tudo, só que eu tenho um select com as modalidades e este select  apresenta todos os escaloes, eu quero colocar data-target para poder filtrar

Comment: Me parece que o que você fez para filtrar por Concelho está correto, está tendo algum problema?

Comment: O problema é criar o data-select= no input option criado em javascript, consigo em php mas javascript ja é outra historia o problema esta mesmo em criar esse atributo no javascript

Comment: qual a versao de jquery? tenta com o attr..  $(this).attr('data-select', 'test')